# Testing a Restangular responseInterceptor

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, restangular

What is the best way to do a unit test on a Restangular responseInterceptor?

For instance:

```
.config(['RestangularProvider', function(RestangularProvider){
    RestangularProvider.setDefaultHttpFields({cache: true, withCredentials: true});
    RestangularProvider.addResponseInterceptor(function (data, operation, what, url, response, deferred) {
        console.log('response from '+ url);
        console.log(data);
        var extractedData;
        // .. to look for getList operations
        if (operation === "getList") {
            // .. and handle the data and meta data
            extractedData = data.data;
            //extractedData.meta = data;
        } else {
            extractedData = data;
        }
        return extractedData;
    });
}])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally resolved to have this bit of code untested. It's essentially a cut and paste from Restangular's documentation anyhow, and other code would be broken if it was broken, as it affects the format that Restangular provides in the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

I tend to be "old school" so I'd make it a named function so I could test it by itself; without having to test by putting data through Restangular.

Here's an example using angular's `$httpBackend`:
http://jbavari.github.io/blog/2014/06/20/testing-interceptor-headers-in-angularjs/

Comment: What I've realized is that my question is more about how do I mock RestangularProvider, which is provided to the anonymous function. I have another instance of this pattern that I need to add a test to as well, so I'm still working on this.

Comment: Since Providers are used to configure services I don't see a need to mock the Provider itself; I'd trust the service's creator to have tests that confirm the Provider correctly enables/modifies the service's behavior. At most I'd want to confirm that the functionality I've enabled/modified via a service's Provider's API is actually being used by the service. In which case the approach used in the blog post using $httpBackend seems appropriate (for $http based services). So I'd perform the testing by exercising the Restangular API and confirming the payload is modified as you'd expect.